# Snowflake cast Int to Decimal

Tags: sql, t-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I'm working on Migrating SQL Server data to Snowflake and trying to convert Int to Decimal. But the response is not what I'm expecting.

In SQL If you run this query `Select 1.0000` or `Select Cast(1 as Decimal(12,4))` the result will `1.000`.
If I do the same in Snowflake the result is 1. Is there a way to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in Snowflake. `select cast(1 as Decimal(12,4))` returns `1.0000` not `1`. Is you data type for said field set to integer by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
select to_number(1,12,4)
```

For more [info](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_decimal.html#to-decimal-to-number-to-numeric)

Answer (score 1):

> *Select Cast(1 as Decimal(12,4)) the result will 1.000. If I do the same in Snowflake the result is 1. Is there a way to fix it?*

Representation of the number does not matter. It is most likely a client tool that shows it without decimal places.

When **EXPLICIT** cast is involved the data type is set as requested and it could be easily confirmed with [DESCRIBE RESULT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/desc-result.html):

```
SELECT CAST(1 AS DECIMAL(12,4)) AS col;

DESCRIBE RESULT LAST_QUERY_ID();
-- name     type           kind      null?
-- col      NUMBER(12,4)   COLUMN    Y
```

DECIMAL and NUMBER are synonyms in Snowflake.